# Pass string values from textbox to code

Tags: matlab, matlab-guide

I have three files in Matlab:

1. `mygui.fig`
2. `mygui.m`
3. `mycode.m`

As the titles suggest, the first two deal with the simple user interface and the last is where my processing takes place.

I have created `mygui.fig` using GUIDE and it looks like this:

[image]

When I hit run, I want the two parameters from the interface to be transferred to `mycode.m`.

I currently have this code in `mygui.m` which captures the data from the textboxes:

```
function btnRun_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
     strPathTrain = get(handles.txtPathTrain,'String');
     strPathTest = get(handles.txtPathTest,'String');
```

`mycode.m` looks like this:

```
Trainset = 'C:\Users\blah1';   
Testset  = 'C:\Users\blah2';
...
```

How can I call and transfer these values to `mycode.m`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can transfer data among them using handles, try it [this](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/153251#answer_150562) way.

For example, in the form code:

```
handles.k.tr = get(handles.txtTr,'String');
handles.k.te = get(handles.txtTe,'String');
guidata( hObject, handles );
somefunction( handles.k );
```

The function:

```
function [ output_args ] = somefunction( k )
     fprintf('tain=%s', k.tr);
     output_args = 0;
end
```

Comment: I have attached the handles to `mygui.m` but how can I get these values from my function in `mycode.m`. Right now, `mycode.m` does not know that there is a another file, aside from the fact that they are in the same folder. I think I'm missing something.

Comment: Have you seen the link? Still struggling?

Comment: This answer has been flagged for removal as a link-only answer because it requires a user to click through the link to see the proposed solution. Could you please edit it to include enough details to solve the problem without clicking the link?

Comment: I request @john to edit how it helped him in his way :)

Comment: Sure. Give me an hour.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a global structure to store all user inputs in `mygui.m` and use that in other functions. 
Alternatively, you can also write the value to a file inside the function and read process the file elsewhere.

Comment: Thanks, I'm new to Matlab so can I ask- are these the standard ways of passing values in Matlab or would you call this a hack?